# onClick event executes as soon as I change the function

Tags: javascript, button, onclick

i am trying to change the onclick value of a Button via Javascript. But in the moment I change its value, the function is executed directly.

document.getElementById('Send').disabled = false;
document.getElementById('Send').addEventListener("click", window.location.href = 'http://www.google.com');

Comment: "the function is executed directly" — `window.location.href = 'http://www.google.com'` **is not a function**!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Second parameter must be a function! Try:

```
document.getElementById('Send')
.addEventListener("click",
function(){window.location.href = 'http://www.google.com'});
```